# How to split an IPV6 nibble?

Tags: subnet, ipv6

I've been tasked with assigning IPV6 addresses to be split into data centers in several different cities, in several different countries in several different continents. Part of the instructions is to use a "2-6-6-2" solution for allocating these IPs (even if there is a better solution I have no choice but to do this), meaning that I'm not splitting on the nibble boundary. My question is, how do I display this as an IPV6 address? I'm aware that splitting on the nibble boundary gives me 0-F to work with for each digit, but how does it work for not splitting on the nibble boundary? How do I represent 6 bits in one digit? I've looked online and all I can find are examples for splitting on the nibble boundary.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the Internet carriers will not advertise a prefix longer than `/48`, so each site should have that length, or shorter. Also, you may find that the carriers in other RIR regions will require addressing from the RIR for that region.

Comment: Is this for real, or homework? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's for homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to count in binary for prefix lengths to make sense. With a 2-6-6-2 solution I assume you're talking about the 16 bits between /48 and /64, basically the bits that an end-site has to create subnets from.

Let's say that you have `2001:db8:1234::/48` for your end-site. That gives you subnets `2001:db8:1234:0000::/64` to `2001:db8:1234:ffff::/64` to work with. Each hexadecimal character represents 4 bits, and as you say the schema you have been handed doesn't align with the hexadecimal characters (basically a natural 4-4-4-4 split).

So, back to binary. Just looking at the 16 bits between the /48 and a /64 gives us:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:0000::/64
1111 1111 1111 1111  =  ..:ffff::/64
```

Now organise them in the 2-6-6-2 split you describe. Let's write every combination of the first two bits. Of course the hexadecimal notation is still based on groups of 4 bits. I'll give you the first and last address of each value of the first two bits:

```
00 000000 000000 00  =  0000 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:0000::/50
00 111111 111111 11  =  0011 1111 1111 1111  =  ..:3fff::/50

01 000000 000000 00  =  0100 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:4000::/50
01 111111 111111 11  =  0111 1111 1111 1111  =  ..:7fff::/50

10 000000 000000 00  =  1000 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:8000::/50
10 111111 111111 11  =  1011 1111 1111 1111  =  ..:bfff::/50

11 000000 000000 00  =  1100 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:c000::/50
11 111111 111111 11  =  1111 1111 1111 1111  =  ..:ffff::/50
```

Let's take the first one: `:0000:` to `:3fff:`. I'm going to give you some examples of the second field (6 bits):

```
00 000000 000000 00  =  0000 0000 0000 0000  =  ..:0000::/56
00 000000 111111 11  =  0000 0000 1111 1111  =  ..:00ff::/56

00 000001 000000 00  =  0000 0001 0000 0000  =  ..:0100::/56
00 000001 111111 11  =  0000 0001 1111 1111  =  ..:01ff::/56

00 000010 000000 00  =  0000 0010 0000 0000  =  ..:0200::/56
00 000010 111111 11  =  0000 0010 1111 1111  =  ..:02ff::/56

etc, let's take some in the middle:

00 010001 000000 00  =  0001 0001 0000 0000  =  ..:1100::/56
00 010001 111111 11  =  0001 0001 1111 1111  =  ..:11ff::/56
...
00 100001 000000 00  =  0010 0001 0000 0000  =  ..:2100::/56
00 100001 111111 11  =  0010 0001 1111 1111  =  ..:21ff::/56

etc, to the last ones:

00 111101 000000 00  =  0011 1101 0000 0000  =  ..:3d00::/56
00 111101 111111 11  =  0011 1101 1111 1111  =  ..:3dff::/56

00 111110 000000 00  =  0011 1101 0000 0000  =  ..:3e00::/56
00 111110 111111 11  =  0011 1101 1111 1111  =  ..:3eff::/56

00 111111 000000 00  =  0011 1101 0000 0000  =  ..:3f00::/56
00 111111 111111 11  =  0011 1101 1111 1111  =  ..:3fff::/56
```

And you do the same for the other bits in the address. It requires a lot more thinking than when you divide on nibble boundaries, but in binary it doesn't matter where you put the boundary. It's just the "human" notation in hexadecimal that gets harder to read/interpret.

Answer (score 0):

You don't represent six bits in one digit. Each digit is four bits. What you do is use the CIDR notation. For example, there are ranges of IPv6 addresses for special functions:

- fe80::/10 for Link-Local
- fc00::/7 for ULA

It is all binary, just like IPv4 where you have addressing that does not map to the octet boundaries.